# WebStorm opens several empty windows

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

When I open my WebStorm project, or switch to a new branch (which restores its workspace or something), the application opens a bunch of empty windows. Recently it was something like 16 windows, but I just restarted my laptop and it opened, along with the window of actual work/files, no less than **55** empty windows alongside!!!

I've tried closing the windows and restarting WebStorm, or closing them and switching branches, to no avail. Also they don't even close with <kbd>Cmd + W</kbd> so I have to close them using the mouse if I want to close them. Craziness!

Help!

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the logs attached (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data).

Comment: This just started happening recently with me as well... v.2021.2.3